# How to add/remove child nodes from textbox to the selected node in combobox

Tags: c#

[image]

- I'm adding items from combobox to treeview at run-time.

The code goes as follows:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        string[] items = new string[comboBox1.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            items[i] = comboBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(items[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Now I want to add child node to the selected node in combobox.**

[image]

When I add child for root node - 2 it goes at the bottom, as displayed in the picture above.

```
 private void AddChildNodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(comboBox1.Text, textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: You must ask two separate questions. The first one is about adding nodes, the second - about the saving and reading of data.

Comment: OK just answer the first question.

Comment: looking to add and remove child nodes from textbox. Please answer that.

Answer (score 0):

To add to a selected note, use the SelectedNode method, and instead of using the combox1 dropdown, you can just select the node in the tree, like below:

```
private void AddChildNodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text)
}
```

If you want to use the combobox, it will be a little slower since you first have to search the treeview using that text

```
       TreeNode[] tns=treeView1.Nodes.Find(comboBox1.Text, true);
        if (tns.Length > 0)
        {

            treeView1.SelectedNode = tns[0];
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text)
        }
```

Comment: What if I do not select node, but I define that it should add in Node - 2

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself, this works for me.

```
treeView1.Nodes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

to next question, keeping the data save.

I want to add selected item in combobox to treeview and remove selected item in combobox.